# How to use jQuery to set value on screen rather than use alert?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox

I am using the code that I will post below.   I generates the password and works fine.   Only problem is that it shows me the regenerated password in the alert box.   I want to echo it on the screen. how can I do that.   Thanks   Using jQuery fancybox and php

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/processPassword.php',
    data: 'newPassword=' + password,
    success: function(success) {
        if(success == 1) {
            alert('The password has been reset. to: ' + password);
            location.href = 'mainpage.php';
        } else {
            alert('The password was not reset.');
        }
    }
});
});

function newPassword() {
        var password = "";
        some logic...
        return password;
}
```

Comment: You're generating a password on the client?  That doesn't seem very secure...

Comment: where have you called newPassword() in your code

Comment: newPassword is called at this page '/processPassword.php'

Comment: pasword is workingfine..I just need to show it withing the fancybox rather than through alert

Comment: You ... call the fancybox function instead of Alert? (and do the redirect in a callback from the fancybox rather than immediately)

Comment: What does `password` hold on this statement `data: 'newPassword=' + password,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  Replace the "alert" call with the jQuery line below to set the HTML of a div...

#### HTML

```
<div id="newPass"></div>
```

#### jQuery

```
//this assumes that "password" has already been setup.
$("#newPass").html(password);
```

I also would strongly advise you to consider having your PHP page generate the password and to use jQuery or something similar to request a PW to be built with server side code.  Making the PW with client side code seems to be a huge security hole, almost like giving the blue prints of the prison to the prisoners...

Answer (score 0):

This is something you could try

```
$.post {
   "processPassword.php",
   { newPassword: 'password' },
   function(data) {
       alert('Your new password is+'+data) ;
});
```

In this the `data` is the value echoed by the page `processPassword.php` not return so you must echo your new password in the end of page or somewhere.